# JsonPath Path Not Found Exception While Data Driving From Jsonfile So As To Randomize the data

Tags: scala, gatling, jsonpath

Is there a Issue to use below code,basically data driving from Jsonfile ,I am creating random numbers below that is eventidStart and eventidEnd are fetching their respective values from Json file which is shown below

```
var idNumbers=(eventidStart to eventidEnd).iterator
def eventidStart: Int  = JsonPath.parse(nameDataSource).read("$. 
[0].eventIdStart")
def eventidEnd: Int  = JsonPath.parse(nameDataSource).read("$. 
[0].eventIdEnd")

def getNextOrgId()=
 {

 if(!idNumbers.hasNext)
  idNumbers=(eventidStart to eventidEnd).iterator
Map("orgId"->idNumbers.next())
 }
```

Here is JsonFile
  `[
    { "eventIdStart": 1000080,
      "eventIdEnd": 1000100
     }
    ]`

Here is Error from console of gatling:-

```
Exception in thread "main" com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException: 
Filter: [0]['eventIdStart'] can only be applied to arrays. Current context 
is: RecordSeqFeederBuilder(Vector(Map(eventIdStart -> 1000080, eventIdEnd 
-> 1000100)),Random)
at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.ArrayPathToken.checkArrayModel(ArrayPathToken.java:184)
at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.ArrayPathToken.evaluate(ArrayPathToken.java:47)
at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.RootPathToken.evaluate(RootPathToken.java:62)
at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.CompiledPath.evaluate(CompiledPath.java:53)
at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.CompiledPath.evaluate(CompiledPath.java:61)
at com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(JsonPath.java:187)
at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.JsonContext.read(JsonContext.java:102)
at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.JsonContext.read(JsonContext.java:89)
at simulations.gamekeeper.eventidStart(gamekeeper.scala:46)
at simulations.gamekeeper.<init>(gamekeeper.scala:45)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at io.gatling.app.Runner.run0(Runner.scala:79)
at io.gatling.app.Runner.run(Runner.scala:64)
at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.start(Gatling.scala:63)
at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.fromMap(Gatling.scala:40)
at GatlingRunner$.main(GatlingRunner.scala:17)
at GatlingRunner.main(GatlingRunner.scala)
  Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is Full code for reference

```
package simulations

import baseConfig.BaseSimulation
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ThreadLocalRandom
import scala.language.postfixOps
import scala.math._

import scala.concurrent.duration.DurationInt
import scala.io.Source

class GamekeeperWithJsonfileAsInputforRandomEvents extends BaseSimulation  
{

val uri03 = "https://api.platform.wizards.com"



  val headers_10 = Map("Content-Type" -> 
  "application/json","Authorization" -> "${token_type} + ${access_token}" 
)

   val usersDataSource=jsonFile("C:data/input-gamekeeper.json").circular
   val  nameDataSource=jsonFile("C:/input-StringBody.json").random
   var idNumbers=(eventidStart to eventidEnd).iterator
  def eventidStart: Int  = JsonPath.parse(nameDataSource).read("$. 
 [0].eventIdStart")
  def eventidEnd: Int  = JsonPath.parse(nameDataSource).read("$. 
 [0].eventIdEnd")




private def getProperty(propertyName: String, defaultValue: String) = {
  Option(System.getenv(propertyName))
    .orElse(Option(System.getProperty(propertyName)))
    .getOrElse(defaultValue)
   }
   // now specify the properties
    //def userCount: Int = getProperty("USERS", "100").toInt

  val source: String =  Source.fromFile("C:/input- 
 gamekeeper.json").getLines.mkString
 def userCount: Int  = JsonPath.parse(source).read("$.[0].user")
 def testDuration: Int  = JsonPath.parse(source).read("$. 
 [0].testDuration")
 def rampDuration: Int  = JsonPath.parse(source).read("$. 
 [0].rampDuration")


 // print out the properties at the start of the test
 before {
   println(s"Running test with ${userCount} users")
   println(s"Ramping users over ${rampDuration} seconds")
   println(s"Total Test duration: ${testDuration} seconds")
 }

  def getNextOrgId()=
  {

   if(!idNumbers.hasNext)
  idNumbers=(eventidStart to eventidEnd).iterator
   Map("orgId"->idNumbers.next())
  }



  val customFeeder=Iterator.continually(getNextOrgId())






  def createEventRound()={
    repeat(990000000){


      exec(flushHttpCache)
      feed(customFeeder)
      .exec(http("CreateEventGameKeeper")


      .post("https://api.cloud/dev/gamekeeper/Round")
      .headers(headers_10)


      .body(StringBody(
        """
          |{
          |  "eventId": ${orgId},
          |  "roundStart": "2019-04-16T18:22:50.388Z",
          |  "roundEnd": "2019-04-16T18:22:50.388Z",
          |  "currentTime": "2019-04-16T18:22:50.388Z",
          |  "roundNumber": 1,
          |  "matches": [
          |    {
          |      "matchId": 0,
          |      "isBye": true,
          |      "tableNumber": "string",
          |      "teams": [
          |        {
          |          "teamId": 0,
          |          "teamName": "string",
          |          "players": [
          |            {
          |              "personaId": "string",
          |              "displayName": "string"
          |            }
          |          ]
          |        }
          |      ]
          |    }
          |  ]
          |}
        """.stripMargin)).asJSON

      .check(status.in(200,201))//checkforaspecificstatus
      .check(jsonPath(path="$.roundNumber").is("1"))
      .check(jsonPath(path="$.eventId").saveAs(key="eventId")))

    .exec{session=>println(session);session}//parameterfortheorgIdgoeshere
    .pause(1)

    }
  }





  val scenario2 = scenario("Post Orgs ")
  .exec(http("Event-Web-Image-Login")
    .get("https://api.cloud/dev/event-reservations- 
    web/img/loading.dfbfd678.svg")
   .headers(headers_1)
   .resources(http("Http Header Token Authentication Url")
     .options(uri03 + "/auth/oauth/token")
     .headers(headers_7),
     http("Token Generation Url For Post")
       .post(uri03 + "/auth/oauth/token")
       .headers(headers_8)
       .formParam("grant_type", "password")
       .formParam("username", "zyh@ws.com")
       .formParam("password", .basicAuth("")
      .check(jsonPath("$.access_token").exists.saveAs("access_token"))
      .check(jsonPath("$.token_type").exists.saveAs("token_type"))





  ))
.forever() { // add in the forever() method - users now loop forever
  exec(createEventRound())


}

 // setup the load profile
 // example command line: ./gradlew gatlingRun- 
 simulations.RuntimeParameters -DUSERS=10 -DRAMP_DURATION=5 -DDURATION=30
 setUp(

 scenario2.inject(
  nothingFor(5 seconds),
  rampUsers(userCount) over ( rampDuration ))
  .protocols(httpConf))


.maxDuration(testDuration)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is related to JAVA code.
Error:
Exception in thread "main" com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException:
Filter: [0]['eventIdStart'] can only be applied to arrays.

Solution:

1. Make a File Object, and pass the 'sourcePath' in same constructor.
2. Make object of 'DocumentContext' and pass the above file object
3. Make a String/ int object (according to requirement) for reading the JSON content.
4. Write: documentContextObject.read("Step 3 Object")

e.g.:  for reading int from JSON file::

```java
File file= new file("SourcePathOfJSONFile");
DocumentContext jsonContext = JsonPath.parse(file);

String path = "$.abc.plm";
int lst= jsonContext.read(path);
```